# Delete the last 3 letters set sas variables

Tags: sas

I would like to delete the last 3 letters from a set of variables in a SAS dataset.
(have to concatenante 2 datasets. )

And in the first set, the variables are named for example:
abc ,
def ,
ghi ...

While in the 2nd set they are named:
abc_1A ,
def_1A ,
ghi_1A ...

How can I delete the '_1A' from the 100+ variables? I don't want to simply add '_1A' to my first Dataset

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options.  Here is one 'safe' option and one 'unsafe' option.

Safe option:

Write a macro to rename a variable to its name without the _1A.;
 Arguments: var = variable name, len = length desired of final variable name.;

```
%macro rename_shorter(var=,len=);
&var. = %substr(&var.,1,&len.)
%mend rename_shorter;
```

Create a list of calls from dictionary.columns;

```
proc sql;
select cats('%rename_shorter(var=',name,',len=',length(name)-3,')') 
 into :renamelist separated by ' '
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname='SASHELP' and upcase(memname)='CLASS';
quit;
```

Call that list;

```
data want;
set sashelp.class(rename=(&renamelist.));
run;
```

An **unsafe** option, in the sense that it doesn't check that things are aligned correctly, is

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
 select * from have_namedright H
 outer union corr
 select * from have_namedwrong W
;
quit;
```

Comment: Note that this code doesn't run as-is because some of the column names are only three characters long.